# How can I fix submenu that won't show?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, navigation

I'm currently running into an issue where my submenu does not display under "shop".
I'm unsure what's causing it to stay hidden i've referenced what's posted here on w3schools https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_subnav.asp for a potential fix but it seems like i've screwed myself there.

```css
    #nav {
        position: absolute;
        display: block;
        top: 6em;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
    }

        #nav > ul {
            display: inline-block;
            border-radius: 0.35em;
            box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25);
            padding: 0 1.5em 0 1.5em;
        }

            #nav > ul > li {
                display: inline-block;
                text-align: center;
                padding: 0 1.5em 0 1.5em;
            }

                #nav > ul > li > ul {
                    display: none;
                }

                #nav > ul > li > a, #nav > ul > li > span {
                    display: block;
                    color: #eee;
                    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
                    text-transform: uppercase;
                    text-decoration: none;
                    font-size: 0.7em;
                    letter-spacing: 0.25em;
                    height: 5em;
                    line-height: 5em;
                    -moz-transition: all .25s ease-in-out;
                    -webkit-transition: all .25s ease-in-out;
                    -o-transition: all .25s ease-in-out;
                    -ms-transition: all .25s ease-in-out;
                    transition: all .25s ease-in-out;
                    outline: 0;
                }

                #nav > ul > li:hover > a {
                    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
                }

                #nav > ul > li.active > a, #nav > ul > li.active > span {
                    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
        }

        #nav > ul > li > ul:hover > a {
          display: block;
                }
```

```html
<nav id="nav">
            <ul>
                <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li class="current"><a href="index.html">Book An Appointment</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Shop</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="yellow.html">Extensions & Wigs</a></li>
                        <li><a href="blue.html">Candles</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="left-sidebar.html">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are trying to hover over a element which hasn't even been rendered inside the DOM... yet. Look at this snipet of your stylesheet.

```
#nav > ul > li > ul {
   display: none;
}
#nav > ul > li > ul:hover > a {
   display: block;
}
```

You are styling the hover pseudo class on the **ul** element which never was displayed.
A better approach would be to use the hover class on the list element itself. Like this:

```
/* from this */
#nav > ul > li > ul:hover > a {
   display: block;
}

/* to this */
#nav>ul>li:hover ul {
   display: block;
}
```

Also, since your **submenu ul** is not placed absolutely inside the **nav**, it will take up space and may result in unexpected design changes on shop hover.

Comment: @peter thanks for the fast response so that did work but you were also correct about the unexpected design change. don't mean to sound ignorant but i'm not following the part about the Submenu ul not being placed absolutely inside the nav. Is it because I didn't specify an ID for it?

Comment: Ok. So when you use `position: relative`, it places your element in relation with the sibling elements and may take up space in the parent div. For example, placing 2 small boxes inside a large boxes. both the boxes would be taking space relative to each other. But when you use `position: absolute`, it places your element with respect to the nearest relative parent. Please read this article to understand things in a better way. [Difference between css position absolute versus relative](https://medium.com/@leannezhang/difference-between-css-position-absolute-versus-relative-35f064384c6)

Answer (score 0):

This is what I got after watching a quick youtube video the submenu now displays but the overall menu resizes itself

```
<div class="nav">
            <ul>
                <li>Home</li>
                <li>Book An Appointment</li>
                <li>Shop
                    <ul>
                        <li>Extensions & Wigs</li>
                        <li>Candles</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

```
.nav {
    position: center;
    display: block;
    top: 6em;
    text-align: center;
    }

    .nav ul {
        display: inline-block;
        border-radius: 0.35em;
        box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25);
        padding: 0 1.5em 0 1.5em;
        }

        .nav ul li {
            display: inline-block;
            text-align: center;
            padding: 0 1.5em 0 1.5em;
            }

            .nav ul ul {
                display: none;
                    }
                    .nav ul li {
            display: block;$$
            color: #eee;
            color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
            text-transform: uppercase;
            text-decoration: none;
            font-size: 0.8em;
            letter-spacing: 0.25em;
            height: 5em;
            line-height: 5em;
                        float: left;
            -moz-transition: all .25s ease-in-out;
            -webkit-transition: all .25s ease-in-out;
            -o-transition: all .25s ease-in-out;
            -ms-transition: all .25s ease-in-out;
            transition: all .25s ease-in-out;
            outline: 0;
                    }

        .nav ul li:hover {
            color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
                }
        .nav ul li.active > a, .nav ul li.active > span {
                color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
        }

        .nav ul li:hover > ul {
          display: block;
                }
```